# I'm having an issue running Nodemon in my project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

I cannot solve this issue. This is the error that appears in the terminal:

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of the entry point of your app, It seems like you don't have a file app.js so it cant find it